# Datavalidation dropdown list - How to prohibit empty value?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I created a dropdown list in Excel with `XSSFDataValidation`.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("test sheet");

XSSFDataValidationHelper helper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) helper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[] { "Checked", "Unchecked" });
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 10, 0, 0);
XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation)helper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
validation.setShowErrorBox(true);

sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

My questions are the following one :

- Is it possible to prohibit empty value? I mean, force the user to put a value in the cell. I tried `validation.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);` but it is still possible to put an empty value.
- There is another way to define a default value than `cell.setCellValue("Unchecked");`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Excel`'s data validation lists it is **not** possible to prohibit empty cells. Set of  **Ignore blank** checkbox unchecked only prevents an existing cell to get changed from any value to an empty value. But selecting a cell in `Excel` and then pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> deletes the whole cell and not only empties the cell value. But the data validation does not work on cells which are not already present. So this is an `Excel` issue and `apache poi` cannot do anything against this since `apache poi` cannot do what `Excel` cannot do.

The best we can do using `Excel`'s data validation and using `apache poi` is telling the users as much and often as possible what they shall do. To do so we can show a input message when cell is selected additional to the error message.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;

class CreateExcelDataValidationList {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
  DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"Checked", "Unchecked"}) ;
  int lastRow = workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion().getLastRowIndex();
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 10, 0, 0);

  DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
  validation.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
  validation.createPromptBox("Prompt", "Please select Cecked or Unchecked from dropdown list.");
  validation.createErrorBox("Error", "Please select Cecked or Unchecked from dropdown list.");
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) validation.setShowPromptBox(true);
  sheet.addValidationData(validation);

  FileOutputStream out = null;
  if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationList.xls");
  } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationList.xlsx");
  }
  workbook.write(out);
  workbook.close();
  out.close();

 }
}
```

And no, there is not another way to define a default value than `cell.setCellValue("Unchecked");`. That is because there is not even a default value in `Excel`'s data validation lists. Using `Excel`'s data validation lists there only is a list of valid values. This list is checked then against the real cell values. And the real cell values will be set using `Cell.setCellValue`.

Comment: Thank you a lot it is better than nothing.

Comment: @Royce: The error message only occurs if the user types something else than the list items into the cells or deletes the cell content in the edit bar. As said in my answer, using the [Del] key not only the cell content gets deleted but the whole cell and thus the error does not occur. I would call that a insufficiency in `Excel`'s data validation. But as also said, this is nothing what `apache poi` could heal. Data validation runs in `Excel`'s `GUI` and `apache poi` does not interact with `Excel`'s `GUI`.